# Linked List Delete Method

Tags: java, linked-list

Could anyone explain why the following delete method does not work? It appears to create an infinite loop at the value I am trying to remove. It should loop through a linked list, delete all instances of the value passed to the method, and return the total number of nodes deleted (`return num;`).

```
public int delete(T value) 
{
    int num = 0;
    ListNode<T> trav = head;
    ListNode<T> next = head.getNext();

    while(trav != null) {
      if(trav.getValue().compareTo(value) == 0) {
        trav = next;            
        num++;
      }
      if(next.getValue().compareTo(value) == 0) {
        trav = next.getNext();
        num++;
      }
      trav = trav.getNext();
    }   

    return num; 
}
```

Comment: You can use your debugger to step through your code however a couple of things are clearly wrong. a) you never update the head b) you never change `next` so when you do `trav = next;` this will take you back to the second element.  c) you don't actually remove any nodes. d) The check for `if(next` doesn't appear to have a point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never change the value of `next`.

```
  if(trav.getValue().compareTo(value) == 0) {
    trav = next;            
    num++;
  }
  if(next.getValue().compareTo(value) == 0) {
    trav = next.getNext();
    num++;
  }
```

Since next never changes, you're comparing the same value in the second `if` every time.

Comment: `trav = trav.getNext();` ?

Comment: Still not changing the value of the `next` variable. You want something more like `next = next.getNext();`